# Grails app (profile rest-api) went haywire after compiling Groovy before Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, grails, gradle, groovy

In my `Grails` app, I explicitly made it to compile `Groovy` before `Java`, by adding this,

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            // override the default locations, rather than adding additional ones
            srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy', 'src/main/java']
        }
        java {
            srcDirs = [] // don't compile Java code twice
        }
    }
}
```

to the `build.gradle`.

After adding this snippet, the application started complaining about Main class,

```
...
...
:findMainClass FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':findMainClass'.
> Illegal null value provided in this collection: [null]
```

when I run `gradle clean build`.

I tried to provide this main class like below,

```
springBoot {
    mainClass = "foo.bar.Application" // The one in the grails-app/init
}
```

but yet to hit another error.

```
...
...
:classes
:findMainClass
:bootRunError: Could not find or load main class foo.bar.Application
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Versions:

- Gradle, 3.4.1
- Grails, 3.2.8
- Groovy, 2.4.7
- Java, 1.8

Comment: Why would you compile Java sources using Groovy compiler?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak, I don't have to. Is there any other way to force Groovy compilation before Java?

Comment: Well, is there any problem you are trying to solve with that? Your Java sources are aware of Groovy source files and use them directly and vice versa. Your `src/main/java` cannot be added to `sourcesSets.main.groovy`, because it contains Java files that Groovy compiler cannot compile. You can try changing order of `sourcesSets.main.groovy` and `sourcesSets.main.java` inside `main` closure, but I guess Gradle doesn't care about order inside the `main` body.

Comment: The problem is, Gradle is not compiling my Java class and complaining about the references of Groovy classes in there. IntelliJ on the other hand is fine. The solution I tried seems very popular, perhaps not very effective with Grails.

Comment: Groovyc falls back to Javac, when seeing a .java file.  It's even encouraged to put the .java files into the .groovy source root usually to not have to deal with circular deps from two different compilers running.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for explaining that, I've never faced issues with groovy and java source sets.

Answer (score 0):

Java cannot use groovy classes natively. They have to be compiled to JVM byte-code before interoperability can be achieved. If you would like to use reusable groovy code in java, the easiest way is to package a groovy library into a JAR file (jvm byte code) independently and use it as a JAR dependency. You would also need the groovy sdk jars when doing this so that java "understands" groovy signatures.

Comment: It would be a nightmare for development. Actually, I can live with what I got -- given it's not about running in an embedded container. Spring Boot can't load the main class for some reason. Application should work if I deploy in Tomcat, in a conventional manner.